# Multiple undefined reference errors in hpp file

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting multiple undefined reference errors from `zmq.hpp`  such as:

```
`build-client-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/../client/Headers/zmq.hpp:113: undefined reference to zmq_errno'
```

and the others are `zmq_strerror, zmq_msg_init` etc. there are like 20 of them.

I guess the hpp file can not find the `zmq.h` ?

I added the headers also in .pro file in QT like:

```
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

HEADERS +=  \
    Headers/zmq.h \
    Headers/zmq.hpp \
    Headers/zmq_utils.h
```

How am I going to link them?

[image: Screenshot from 2021-11-17 08-41-15]

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: 1) Please copy/paste the actual ERROR MESSAGE TEXT.  Screen shots are discouraged.  Your particular screen shot is illegible.  2) This sounds like a LINK error, not a "compile" error.  That means that zmq.h is the correct header; the problem is that you're not linking the ZeroMQ *LIBRARY*.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. QT does not allow me to copy all the error messages. So I copied and pasted 1 of them since the others are the same. I put the screenshot not for the error message but just to show the files in the project, to show where is where. I know it looks strange but since I don't know where is the problem, I just wanted to show what I can

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error, you forgot to add library to your .pro file. The line looks like this `LIBS +=lib_path/lib_name`